# MySQL Update Query Optimization - Subqueries or not?

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

Which query would be the fastest: My own tests do not show any obvious results:

#### query1:

```
UPDATE items, brands SET items.brand_id = brands.id WHERE brands.name = 'apple'
```

--vs--

#### query2:

```
UPDATE items SET brand_id = (SELECT id FROM brands WHERE name = 'apple')
```

I can't find any data on this with Google; maybe some SQL experts here know the answer?

Looking just at the syntax I personally prefer the first. Whilst others I speak prefer the second (for being more obvious)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect them to run equally fast, but running tests on ~4M records innoDB table shows the following results:

```
mysql> update t, (select now() value) onerow set update_date = onerow.value;
Query OK, 3999960 rows affected (2 min 12.32 sec)
Rows matched: 3999960  Changed: 3999960  Warnings: 0

mysql> update t set update_date = (select now());
Query OK, 3999960 rows affected (1 min 28.66 sec)
Rows matched: 3999960  Changed: 3999960  Warnings: 0
```

(running test the second time resulted in 2 min 11.52 sec and 1 min 26.67 sec, respectively)

The reasons might be in the different way mysql treats single table updates and multi table updates, [see docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Note: while at it read about how mysql treats `UPDATE` - it has some horrible deviations from SQL standard (it is sensitive to order of assignment, which is not even consistent between single table update and multiple table update - with multiple table update basically being non deterministic in statements such as `UPDATE t SET column1=column1+100, column2=column1`)

Comment: Awesome response.. Coudnt imagine the difference being 40%

Answer (score 0):

The first query will effectively do a [cross-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) before the update, which it the terrible performance wise.

The second query will run that subquery for every row in the outer table, which is very bad performance wise.

Neither is particularly good... just a matter of which is worse. :)

Do you mean to be updating your entire `items` table?

Have you tried looking @ the `EXPLAIN`s of the equivilent `SELECT`s of the two queries?

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT items.brand_id, brands.id 
FROM items, brands 
WHERE brands.name = 'apple'
```

and

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT brand_id, id
FROM items, (SELECT id FROM brands WHERE name = 'apple') a
```

Even better yet, run the `UPDATE`s / equivilent `SELECTS`s and do some `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'handler_%'` to see exactly how many rows are being read/written.

Comment: Well, the actually query contains a where on both the items and brands table. Both matching a unique row. The problem is I recieve the brand name. and need to get the ID of the brand to match it to the item. What would be the "best case scenario". Actually doing seperate querys? first retrieving the ID from the brand, then just using it in the update query? I haven't Explained the query's yet. just got home from work, I will do tomorrow and see if I can find big differences between the querys.